# wp-admin folder removed by hacker

Tags: wp-admin, hacked

My website got hacked recently & i can't login into the admin panel, the hacker removed `wp-admin` folder in root. Now when i try to login, i get too many redirect errors.

Comment: Have you tried replacing those folders from a fresh installation of WordPress?